Prove by induction that $a^n<b^n \implies a<b$ given $a,b \geq 0$
Problem Statement:
Prove that in any ordered field, $a<b$ iff $a^n < b^n$, provided $a,b \geq 0$. Infer that $a^n < 1$ if $0 \leq a <1$; $a^n >1$ if $a>1$ ($n=1,2,\ldots$).
Context:
Naturally, we can use the axioms of an ordered field, specifically the following: Closure; Associativity; Commutativity; Properties of neutral elements; Properties of inverse elements; Distributive property; Trichotomy; Transitivity; Monotonicity of addition and multiplication. Further, the laws of induction, along with an inductive definition of natural powers of a field:
Given an element $x$ of a field $F$, we define the $n$-th power of $x$, denoted
\begin{align*}
 \text{(i)}\;\; x^1 =x\;\; \text{and}\;\; \text{(ii)}\;\; x^n = x^{n-1}x,\; n =2,3, \ldots 
\end{align*}
Attempted Solution:
First, to prove that $a<b$ iff $a^n<b^n$, we need to prove both directions of the statement: $a<b \implies a^n <b^n$ and $a^n < b^n \implies a<b$. Thus, we can define two propositions:
\begin{align*}
 P(n) := a<b \implies a^n<b^n \\
 P'(n) := a^n<b^n \implies a<b
\end{align*}
given that $a,b \geq 0$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Now, we prove $P(n)$:

$P(1)$  is true; we are given, $a<b$. From the inductive definition of $a^1 = a$ and $b^1 =b$, thus, $a^1=a < b = b^1$, hence $a^1<b^1$, showing that $P(1)$ holds.
$P(m) \implies P(m+1)$; assuming $P(n)$ holds for some $m$, we have $a<b \implies a^m <b^m$. For $m+1$, we have $a^{m+1} = a^ma$, from the definition of natural powers. We also have $a<b$ from the proposition, thus, $a^{m+1}=a^ma<b^ma<b^mb=b^{m+1}$, hence $a^{m+1}<b^{m+1}$. Thus, $P(m+1)$ is true when $P(m)$ holds.

By, the principle of induction, given $a,b\geq 0$, $a<b \implies a^n <b^n$ for all natural $n$ of an ordered field. For $P'(n)$, we use the second induction law,:

$P'(1)$  is true; we are given $a^1<b^1$, but by the definition of natural powers, we have $a^1=a$ and $b^1=b$, thus, $a<b$ as required, showing that $P'(1)$ holds.
$P'(1), \ldots, P'(m-1) \implies P'(m)$; by assuming $P'(n)$ holds for all $n < m$, specifically holding for $n=1$ and $n=m-1$, we have:
\begin{align*}
   a^{1}<b^{1} \implies a<b, \\
   a^{m-1}<b^{m-1} \implies a<b
  \end{align*}
with, $a^m=a^{m-1}\cdot a^1<b^{m-1}\cdot a < b^{m-1} \cdot b = b^{m}$, thus, from $P'(1)$ and $P'(m-1)$ we have $a^m<b^m$ also implying that $a<b$.

Hence, by the principle of induction, given $a,b\geq 0$, for any natural element $n$ of an ordered field, $a^n<b^n$ implies $a<b$.
Concerns:

Are the inductive propositions $P(n)$, and espcially, $P'(n)$ valid?
Is there a way we can use the first induction law instead for $P'(n)$? Note that the complication is in the inductive step:

We have to show given that, $a^m<b^m \implies a<b$, we have $a^{m+1}<b^{m+1} \implies a<b$. Thus, we effectively have to show that $a^{m+1}<b^{m+1} \implies a^m<b^m$, only then can we conclude that $a^{m+1}<b^{m+1} \implies a<b$.

By $P(n)$ we have $a<b \implies a^n < b^n$, $a=b\implies a^n=b^n$ and $a>b\implies a^n>b^n$. So $a^n<b^n \text{ and NOT}  a<b$ gives a contradiction. I question the proof using $P'(n)$ but have not carefully consider it.

You can probably prove the contrapositive $a\ge b\implies a^n\ge b^n$ in the same manner you proved the direct way and avoid the hassle of the descending recursion.

@zwim Great Idea. Much simpler than my solution.
